# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied - by running a python script

Tags: node.js, bash, macos, permission-denied

After the installation of my new react env i'm facing multiple problem with my shell.
My python env is activated as always but if i run my script i get a permission denied to the file the script is looking for.

i've tried conda update brew update etc. but there is one special thing i was wondering about. before i'got my machine name displayed in shell now i only the env. ((base)~$)

```
Opening excel file...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Dominik/OneDrive/OneDrive - Celona Gastro GmbH/ControllingDocs/BWAReader/BWAReader.py", line 145, in <module>
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook (path)
  File "/Users/Dominik/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 311, in load_workbook
    data_only, keep_links)
  File "/Users/Dominik/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 126, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "/Users/Dominik/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 98, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "/Users/Dominik/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py", line 1204, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/Dominik/OneDrive/OneDrive - Celona Gastro GmbH/BWAReader/BWA Zusammenfassung 2019-04.xlsx'
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Did you tried to give read permissions to the file? Can you open the file directly from the command line?

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with the. if i tried open open it with the command line i get this: (base) ~ $ cd Users/Dominik/OneDrive/OneDrive - Celona Gastro GmbH/BWAReader/BWA Zusammenfassung 2019-04.xlsx
-bash: cd: Users/Dominik/OneDrive/OneDrive: No such file or directory

Comment: You have spaces in your path: quote or escape them. Otherwise, as you can see, the shell tries to go to the folder formed up to the first space.

Comment: doesn't work..and before i want to learn react this weekend the path was the same

Comment: So this is the culprit.  If the file is there, give the proper permissions to the file so it works and then the script should have no problems accessing it either. If the file is not there, search for the file and update the paths accordingly.