# Making a text file which will contain my list items and applying regular expression to it

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am supposed to make a code which will read a text file containing some words with some common linguistic features. Apply some regular expression to all of the words and write one file which will have the changed words.

For now let's say my text file named `abcd.txt` has these words

```
king
sing
ping
cling
booked
looked
cooked
packed
```

My first question starts from here. In my simple text file how to write these words to get the above mentioned results. Shall I write them line-separated or comma separated?

This is the code provided by user palvarez.

```
import re
with open("new_abcd", "w+") as new, open("abcd") as original:
    for word in original:
      new_word = re.sub("ing$", "xyz", word)
      new.write(new_word)
```

Can I add something like -

```
with open("new_abcd", "w+") as file, open("abcd") as original:
    for word in original:
      new_aword = re.sub("ed$", "abcd", word)
      new.write(new_aword)
```

in the same code file? I want something like -

```
kabc
sabc
pabc
clabc
bookxyz
lookxyz
cookxyz
packxyz
```

PS - I don't know whether mentioning this is necessary or not, but I am supposed to do this for a Unicode supported script Devanagari. I didn't use it here in my examples because many of us here can't read the script. Additionally that script uses some diacritics. eg. 'का' has one consonant character 'क' and one vowel symbol 'ा' which together make 'का'. In my regular expression I need to condition the diacritics.

Comment: Check out [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace pattern matches

Comment: It says `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)` which in my case will be `re.sub(ing$,xyz$)` till the replacement argument, but what about the string argument? I have all my strings dumped in `mylist` variable.

Comment: You need to iterate over your file and the replace string is a string not a pattern. Check out my response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the approach you have with one word by line is better since you don't have to trouble yourself with delimiters and striping.

With a file like this:

```
king
sing
ping
cling
booked
looked
cooked
packed
```

And a code like this, using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace a pattern:

```
import re
with open("new_abcd.txt", "w") as new, open("abcd.txt") as original:
    for word in original:
      new_word = re.sub("ing$", "xyz", word)
      new_word = re.sub("ed$", "abcd", new_word)
      new.write(new_word)
```

It creates a resulting file:

```
kxyz
sxyz
pxyz
clxyz
bookabcd
lookabcd
cookabcd
packabcd
```

I tried out with the diacritic you gave us and it seems to work fine:

```
print(re.sub("ा$", "ing", "का"))
>>> कing
```

EDIT: added multiple replacement. You can have your replacements into a list and iterate over it to do `re.sub` as follows.

```
import re

# List where first is pattern and second is replacement string
replacements = [("ing$", "xyz"), ("ed$", "abcd")]

with open("new_abcd.txt", "w") as new, open("abcd.txt") as original:
    for word in original:
      new_word = word
      for pattern, replacement in replacements:
        new_word = re.sub(pattern, replacement, word)
        if new_word != word:
           break
      new.write(new_word)
```

This limits one modification per word, only the first that modifies the word is taken.

Comment: I had this error `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'new_abcd'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337540/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-by-running-a-python-script this question helped me out. There was a space in my path.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have one more question. Can I use multiple conditions like this in the same code file?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple conditions? Could you give an example of what you need?

Comment: @Niranjan Yes, you can add all the `sub` you need in the same loop, right before the `new.write()` line of course.

Comment: Almost everything is great, just a last doubt. eg. I have one new entry named `xyz` in my main data file. ie. `abcd`. I have a special condition for it i.e. change it to abc. I can manage it with the things that you taught me in this answer, but the problem is `xyz` which is 'obtained' by the function in the first four entries is also changed to abc after compiling this. I also found one hack by putting the last condition first and I got what I wanted, but still I want to know is there any way to protect our changed words from getting changed afterwards?

Comment: @Niranjan Yes, you could have all your replacements done in the original word and then checked if any of the output altered the word.

Comment: I didn't get this? Can you please ellaborate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199308/discussion-between-palvarez-and-niranjan).

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended that for starters, utilize the `with` context manager to open your file, this way you do not need to explicitly `close` the file once you are done with it.

Another added advantage is then you are able to process the file line by line, this will be very useful if you are working with larger sets of data. Writing them in a single line or `csv` format will then all depend on the requirement of your output and how you would want to further process them.

As an example, to read from a file and say substitute a substring, you can use `re.sub`.

```
import re

with open('abcd.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        #do something here
        print(re.sub("ing$",'ring',line.strip()))

>>
kring
sring
pring
clring
```

Another nifty trick is to manage both the input and output utilizing the same context manager like:

```
import re

with open('abcd.txt', 'r') as f, open('out_abcd.txt', 'w') as o:
    for line in f:
        #notice that we add '\n' to write each output to a newline
        o.write(re.sub("ing$",'ring',line.strip())+'\n')
```

This create an output file with your new contents in a very memory efficient way.

If you'd like to write to a `csv` file or any other specific formats, I highly suggest you spend sometime to understand Python's input and output functions [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#). If linguistics in text is what you are going for that understand encoding of different languages and further study Python's [regex operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: I am getting this error - `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abcd'`

Comment: Whereas I've a file named `abcd`. Actually I'm doing it in `gedit` on Ubuntu system. It generates files without extensions.