# Array of strings with re

Tags: arrays

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57874896/11358511) answer suggested me a code for having an array of conditions for replacements. Now I want to have one more condition which cannot be coded in the same way.

```
kxyz
sxyz
pxyz
clxyz
bookabcd
lookabcd
cookabcd
packabcd
bank
lab
court
catch
```

This is the updated word list

```
import re

# List where first is pattern and second is replacement string
replacements = [("ing$", "xyz"), ("ed$", "abcd")]

with open("new_abcd.txt", "w") as new, open("abcd.txt") as original:
    for word in original:
      new_word = word
      for pattern, replacement in replacements:
        new_word = re.sub(pattern, replacement, word)
        if new_word != word:
           break
      new.write(new_word)
```

Let's say I want to code a conditions for words like 'bank', 'lab', 'court', 'catch' that says add "x". One may wonder what is a pattern in these words. It's nothing but all of these words are consonant ending. I don't know the Python way of doing this, but I want something like if the word *does not* end in ("a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u") change it to something else. Can `re` handle this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not hard to check with regex whether the word ends in a non-vowel, but in this case you would not replace but just if you have a match, add a letter to the word.

The regex which will check the non-existence of a vowel at the end of the given string is

`[^aeiou]{1}$`

Then in python I guess do something like

`regexp = re.compile(r'[^aeiou]{1}$')
if regexp.search(word):
  word += 'x'
  # do more stuff`

I would check thoroughly whether python built in ways to do this are not faster.

Comment: It is giving me a type error. `expected a string or byte-like object.`

Comment: Yeah I do not do python. You tagged this regex :)